# Confusing bug with brackets on my function

Tags: python, recursion

```
def cube_of(valz):    
    '''Returns the cube of values'''    
    if len(valz) == 0:    
        return 0    
    else:    
        new_val = [valz[0] ** 3]    
        return  [new_val] + [cube_of(valz[1:])]
```

So I am making this function for a demonstration which takes a list of values called `valz` and takes the cube of each value and then returns a list of these cubes.

For example, let's say the input is `[-1,2,-3,4,-5]` - it should return `[-1,8,-27,64,-125]` but it returns `[-1, [8, [-27, [64, [-125, 0]]]]]`.
What is causing the extra brackets? If I remove the brackets in the code then it either gives the sum of these cubes (which is not correct) or it gives an error (something about adding an `int` to a `list`). I tried to debug this and even had my friend take a look but we're both pretty stumped.

Comment: Having trouble with the formatting on mobile :/

Comment: add 4 spaces before every line of code to correctly format it on SO.

Comment: Huh someone managed to edit the formatting for me didn't know that was possible thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `valz` is empty you should return empty list instead of `0` - `return []`

`new_valz` is a list so you don't need brackets. `cube_of` returns list so you don't need brackets too.

```
def cube_of(valz):    
    '''Returns the cube of values'''    
    if len(valz) == 0:    
        return []    
    else:    
        new_val = [valz[0] ** 3]    
        return  new_val + cube_of(valz[1:])

cube_of([-1,2,-3,4,-5])
# [-1,8,-27,64,-125]

cube_of([])
# []
```

Comment: Thank you good sir! Pretty frustrating that I was two brackets away from the solution the whole time but I've got it now! Thanks so much. Do I hit the check mark to put yours as he solution?

Answer (score 2):

`cube_of(valz[1:])` is already a list. There's no need to wrap it in brackets.

```
return [new_val] + cube_of(valz[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be simplified

using *list comprehension:*

```
def cube_of(valz):        
    return [item**3 for item in valz]
```

*Recursive* approach:

```
def cube_of(valz):
    return [valz[0]**3] + cube_of(valz[1:]) if valz else []
```

Sample run:

```
>>> cube_of([-1,2,-3,4,-5])
[-1, 8, -27, 64, -125]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this demonstration is about recursion. List comprehension would be much easier :/

Comment: @Jawndoyghboi1569: No issues. Recursive approach is also simpler. Updater answer with that one as well :)

Answer (score 0):

`cube_of(valz)` already returns an initial segment of the list in the `else` part of the branch, i.e. `[new_val]`. Therefore, in order for its overall return value to be of type list, it should return lists in all its branches.

You should change the function like this:

```
def cube_of(valz):    
    '''Returns the cube of values'''    
    if len(valz) == 0:    
       return []    
    else:    
       new_val = [valz[0] ** 3]    
       return [new_val] + cube_of(valz[1:])
```

Note that now, since both branches of the if-else return an initial segment of the final list, `cube_of` itself now returns a list by induction, thereby making the entire recursive call return a value of list type.

However, if you're looking for an elegant and more idiomatic/Pythonic solution, look no further than anonymous'.